# How to save a .wav file you created in python to a specify directory?

Tags: python, audio, path, operating-system, wav

I made a program that's supposed to record people in my household talking for 1 minute. I think my code has successfully (though messily) been able to save the *.wav file and classifying the recording on gender. The male recordings are supposed to be saved in the male_voices folder and the female recording are supposed to be saved in the female_voices folder.

My question is: I have searched and couldn't seem to find a way to save these recordings to a specific file path. As you can see I tried using

```
os.join(path, "son.wav")
```

but it doesn't work.

My code is as follows:

```
# import required libraries
import sounddevice as sd
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
import wavio as wv
import os
male_members ={'s':'son', 'b':'brother', 'u':'uncle', 'f':'father', 'n':'nephew', 'mc':'male cousin', 'o':'other'}
female_members ={'d':'daughter', 's':'sister', 'a':'aunt', 'm':'mother', 'n':'niece', 'fc':'female cousin', 'o':'other'}
# Sampling frequency
freq = 44100

# Recording duration
duration = 60

while True:
    user = str(input("Do you want to record a female [f] or male [m] voice or exit[e]? "))
    if user.lower() == 'm':
        path = r"C:\Users\core i5\Desktop\GitHub\DataSci\Data Analysis and Tools\Dataset\male_voices"
        male = str(input("Are you recording your son[s], brother[b], uncle[u], father[f], nephew[n], male cousin[mc], or other[o]? "))
        recording = sd.rec(int(duration * freq), samplerate=freq, channels=2)
        sd.wait(60)
        sound_name = f"{male_members[f'{male}']}.wav"
        wv.write(sound_name, recording, freq, sampwidth=2)
        os.path.join(path, sound_name)

    elif user.lower() == 'f':
        path = r"C:\Users\core i5\Desktop\GitHub\DataSci\Data Analysis and Tools\Dataset\female_voices"
        female = str(input("Are you recording your daughter[d], sister[s], aunt[a], mother[m], niece[n], female cousin[fc], or other[o]? "))
        recording = sd.rec(int(duration * freq), samplerate=freq, channels=2)
        sd.wait(60)
        sound_name = f"{female_members[f'{female}']}.wav"
        wv.write(sound_name, recording, freq, sampwidth=2)
        os.path.join(path, sound_name)

    elif user.lower() == 'e':
        print("exiting program....")
        break

    else:
        print("Unrecognized command. Try again\n")
        continue
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: For some additional clarification, what is happening with the above code? Are you getting an error or is it not saving in the correct directory?

Comment: You're calling `os.path.join(path, sound_name)` but not using the return value anywhere! Try `wv.write(os.path.join(path, sound_name), recording, freq, sampwidth=2)`.

Comment: @PaulBurkart the code works in the sense that a .wav is created with the correct family 'name' like son.wav. daughter.wav... but the file is saved in the folder where the code is being executed. I'd like to change it so that the recordings are saved to the path files mentioned in the code.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel omg it worked! Thank you! But how did it work? As I know it the first parameter is supposed to just be used to name the recording. So it is also used to direct where the .wav file will go?

Comment: Someone else can explain it better than I, but when you specify a filename as being (for example) `/test/file.txt`, it just appends that onto the current working directory. Because the forward slash denotes a directory, it is automatically interpreted as such. The actual name of the file itself is "file.txt", but you are more specifying its absolute path rather than just the name of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Justin said you aren't assigning the return value of os.path.join anywhere. This will create a path, but if you aren't doing anything with it, nothing happens.

You have to use the `.write()` function to write the file to the os.path.join return value.

This code should work.

```
# import required libraries
import sounddevice as sd
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
import wavio as wv
import os
male_members ={'s':'son', 'b':'brother', 'u':'uncle', 'f':'father', 'n':'nephew', 'mc':'male cousin', 'o':'other'}
female_members ={'d':'daughter', 's':'sister', 'a':'aunt', 'm':'mother', 'n':'niece', 'fc':'female cousin', 'o':'other'}
# Sampling frequency
freq = 44100

# Recording duration
duration = 60

while True:
    user = str(input("Do you want to record a female [f] or male [m] voice or exit[e]? "))
    if user.lower() == 'm':
        path = r"C:\Users\core i5\Desktop\GitHub\DataSci\Data Analysis and Tools\Dataset\male_voices"
        male = str(input("Are you recording your son[s], brother[b], uncle[u], father[f], nephew[n], male cousin[mc], or other[o]? "))
        recording = sd.rec(int(duration * freq), samplerate=freq, channels=2)
        sd.wait(60)
        sound_name = f"{male_members[f'{male}']}.wav"
        wv.write(os.path.join(path, sound_name), recording, freq, sampwidth=2)
        
    elif user.lower() == 'f':
        path = r"C:\Users\core i5\Desktop\GitHub\DataSci\Data Analysis and Tools\Dataset\female_voices"
        female = str(input("Are you recording your daughter[d], sister[s], aunt[a], mother[m], niece[n], female cousin[fc], or other[o]? "))
        recording = sd.rec(int(duration * freq), samplerate=freq, channels=2)
        sd.wait(60)
        sound_name = f"{female_members[f'{female}']}.wav"
        wv.write(os.path.join(path, sound_name), recording, freq, sampwidth=2)

    elif user.lower() == 'e':
        print("exiting program....")
        break

    else:
        print("Unrecognized command. Try again\n")
        continue
```

`os.path.join(path, sound_name)` would return
"C:\Users\core i5\Desktop\GitHub\DataSci\Data Analysis and Tools\Dataset\male_voices\son.wav" (for example). So by writing this code, all you're doing is building a string essentially and returning it no where.

Comment: Yep exactly. You're just specifying the absolute path to the file, which includes its file name

Comment: Okay. I think I understand it now. the .write() path takes the file name created from the `os.path.join(path, sound_name)` and that is where the recording (the 2nd argument to `wv.write()`) is going to be saved at. Am I also right to assume that .write() is a method of wavio? All this time I was thinking I could somehow save the *.wav file just by using the module os alone... because that is what I was searching for. But how come we can simply use `os.path.join(path, "name.txt")` ? Wouldn't that create a text file in the path directory?

Comment: All os.path.join does is creates the path itself. With that alone you can't create any files. And yes, you are using wavio's `write()` function, since you are importing `wavio as wv` and then calling `wv.write()`. From the documentation: `wavio.write` writes a numpy array to a WAV file

Answer (score 0):

One more trick you can try

```
Import os
curr_dir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(path)
# perform the write operation with path as filename
os.chdir(curr_dir)
```

This is a bit longer than other methods
But this is also a way you can try